# DALEX error when trying to explain iris random forest model

Tags: r, dalex

I want to create explanator with  Dalex of RandomForest model, but when trying I got this error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Here my code:

```
library(DALEX)
library(ranger) 
model <- ranger(Species ~ .,data = iris,probability =T,classification = T)
explanation <- explain(model,
                      data=iris,
                      y = iris$Species,
                      model_info = "classification",
                      label="Random Forest")
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have try with this code

```
library(DALEX)
library(ranger)
model <- ranger(Species ~ .,iris)
model_info <- list(package = "ranger", ver = "0.12.1", type = "classification")

explanation <- explain(model,
                       data=iris,
                       y = iris$Species,
                      
                       label="Random Forest")


plot(model_profile(explanation))
```

But this do not print the influence of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `model_info` or use it as follows:

```
# needs to be a list. Not all items are needed. You could just use type.
model_info <- list(package = "ranger", ver = "0.12.1", type = "classification")

explanation <- explain(model,
                      data=iris,
                      y = iris$Species,
                      model_info = model_info,
                      label="Random Forest")
```

Though when I do this I get a warning message, because y (Species) is a factor. You do not get this warning message if you remove the factor from species, or do not use model_info.

Comment: It do not plot the Partial dependencies plots, how must i deal with iris$Species?

Comment: @jff,  'plot(model_profile(explanation))' should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. I have edit the question